# When using os.stat, is a meta variable created?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I'm currently learning python using this guide (if you want more context) http://www.diveintopython3.net/comprehensions.html#dictionarycomprehension

```
>>> import os, glob, humansize
>>> metadata_dict = {f:os.stat(f) for f in glob.glob('*')}                                  ①
>>> humansize_dict = {os.path.splitext(f)[0]:humansize.approximate_size(meta.st_size) \     
...                   for f, meta in metadata_dict.items() if meta.st_size > 6000}          ②
>>> list(humansize_dict.keys())                                                             ③
['romantest9', 'romantest8', 'romantest7', 'romantest6', 'romantest10', 'pluraltest6']
>>> humansize_dict['romantest9']                                                            ④
'6.5 KiB'
```

Why is it 'humansize.approximate_size(meta.st_size)' and where has the meta variable in 'for f, meta' came from?

Comment: You are looping over `meta_dict.items()`, so `meta` is the value in the key-value pairs (`f` being the key). No idea where the `humansize.approximate_size()` came from here, that would be from an import. `meta_dict` is the dictionary you created with the `os.stat(f)` expression forming the values, so `meta` is referencing whatever `os.stat(f)` returned before.

Comment: `metadata_dict.items()` returns a tuple or pair of `(key, value)` from your `metadata_dict` dictionary, `f` is the key and `meta` is the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `os.stat`.

You seem to have skipped over the subject of that chapter, comprehensions - this is a dict comprehension. As in the earlier discussion of list comprehensions, the dict comp creates variables for each item in the dict it is iterating over. This is explained in the footnotes to that very piece of code.